# Can Freemember be used for the "Account Activated" EE screen?

Tags: freemember, registration, activation

EE 2.8.1, Freemember 2.3.2

I'm working on a site where member registration is set to "Self Activation via Email". When a user clicks on the activation link in the email they receive after initial registration, they get sent to the ugly gray box EE profile template screen that states "Thank You! Your account has been activated, etc". Is there any way for Freemember to manage this screen as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no, I don't believe Freemember has template tags to adjust the email activation page.

This could probably be added to freemember with a pull request though, the same way the reset password process works.